# JSoup Wikipedia scraping join <a and <a separated by <br>

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I have HTML that looks like this.

```html
<td class="" style="" itemprop="">
    <a href="abcdef" title="abcdef">abcdef</a>
    <a href="ABCDEF" title="ABCDEF">ABCDEF</a>
    <br>
    <a href="xyz" title="xyz">xyz</a>
    <a href="XYZ" title="XYZ">XYZ</a>
</td>
```

I want to parse this with JSoup and create a list like this: `[abcdefABCDEF, xyzXYZ]`

…but I have no idea how to do it. Any suggestion?

td does not always have `<a> <a> <br> <a> <a>` structure. Its sometimes  `<a> <a> <br> <a>` or  `<a> <br> <a> <a>`

Comment: Select the `td` first, then you can select and iterate through the `a` elements inside it.

Comment: could be more specific? I've already figured out selecting td and doing for loop for a. But I am not sure how to join a and separate them when there is <br>

Comment: Easily done. Loop over `children()`, keep a `List<Element>` and append to it, every time you see a <br> you process and clear the list, and at the end too. The first processing is triggered by <br> and produces "abcdefABCDEF", the second by the end of the list and produces "xyzXYZ".

Comment: Your suggested method seemed to be working!! Thank you so much!!